# How to remove panes from Compiler Explorer?

Tags: compiler-explorer

How to remove panes from Compiler Explorer?

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) displays one or more panes. Here there are four panes. How does one remove the two right panes?

[image: Compiler Explorer page with four panes]

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: there's a reset option in the More menu.

Answer (score 0):

The X - close panes controls are missing. Restore them with:

```
More>Reset Code and UI layout
```

[image]

Then close panes as needed.

[image]

As noted by Daniel A. White